# Training muscles for scuba diving

Tags: swimming, legs, home-exercise

I'm a keen trail runner, and when scuba diving you're using only your legs to propel, so in theory everything should be fine. However, I'm getting cramps and I need to move slowly to prevent them.

It looks like the movement and the muscle load is different enough, between trail running and scuba diving, to cause problems.

I'm using hard technical fins for frog kicks.

Are there any device-free exercises that can help me train the muscles needed for scuba diving in my home?

Comment: Where are you getting cramp? Feet and calf muscles are the classic issues. I'm also interested why you're using frog kick instead of flutter kick, but that's more personal curiosity.

Comment: @DarkHippo calves. Every experienced diver will tell you, that flutter kicks are terrible. The reason is, you make turbulences that turbid the mud even if you're doing flutter kicks, you create turbulence that turbid the sediments below you. Frog kicks, when done correctly, create turbulence behind and above you, not below.

Comment: That kind of depends on where and how you're diving. I spent a fair amount of time leading dives in the Caribbean, and flutter kicks kicking up sediment were never an issue.

Comment: @DarkHippo OK fair point, in lakes we have limited sight and dive near surface , so it's a quite huge topic. And many are cave divers, which puts that issue on another level.